# Easiest way to represent Euclidean Distance in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I am writing a data mining algorithm in Scala and I want to write the Euclidean Distance function for a given test and several train instances. I have an `Array[Array[Double]]` with test and train instances. I have a method which loops through each test instance against all training instances and calculates distances between the two (picking one test and train instance per iteration) and returns a `Double`.

Say, for example, I have the following data points:

```
testInstance = Array(Array(3.2, 2.1, 4.3, 2.8))
trainPoints = Array(Array(3.9, 4.1, 6.2, 7.3), Array(4.5, 6.1, 8.3, 3.8), Array(5.2, 4.6, 7.4, 9.8), Array(5.1, 7.1, 4.4, 6.9))
```

I have a method stub (highlighting the distance function) which returns neighbours around a given test instance:

```
def predictClass(testPoints: Array[Array[Double]], trainPoints: Array[Array[Double]], k: Int): Array[Double] = {

    for(testInstance <- testPoints)
    {
        for(trainInstance <- trainPoints) 
        {
            for(i <- 0 to k) 
            {
                distance = euclideanDistanceBetween(testInstance, trainInstance) //need help in defining this function
            }
        }
    }    
    return distance
}
```

I know how to write a generic Euclidean Distance formula as:

```
math.sqrt(math.pow((x1 - y1), 2) + math.pow((x2 - y2), 2))
```

I have some pseudo steps as to what I want the method to do with a basic definition of the function:

```
def distanceBetween(testInstance: Array[Double], trainInstance: Array[Double]): Double = {
  // subtract each element of trainInstance with testInstance
  // for example, 
  // iteration 1 will do [Array(3.9, 4.1, 6.2, 7.3) - Array(3.2, 2.1, 4.3, 2.8)]
  // i.e. sqrt(3.9-3.2)^2+(4.1-2.1)^2+(6.2-4.3)^2+(7.3-2.8)^2
  // return result
  // iteration 2 will do [Array(4.5, 6.1, 8.3, 3.8) - Array(3.2, 2.1, 4.3, 2.8)]
  // i.e. sqrt(4.5-3.2)^2+(6.1-2.1)^2+(8.3-4.3)^2+(3.8-2.8)^2
  // return result, and so on......
  }
```

How can I write this in code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the formula you put in only works for two-dimensional vectors.  You have four dimensions, but you should probably write your function to be flexible on this.  So check out [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#n_dimensions).

So what you really want to say is:

```
for each position i:
  subtract the ith element of Y from the ith element of X
  square it
add all of those up
square root the whole thing
```

To make this more functional-programming style it will be more like:

```
square root the:
  sum of:
    zip X and Y into pairs
    for each pair, square the difference
```

So that would look like:

```
import math._

def distance(xs: Array[Double], ys: Array[Double]) = {
  sqrt((xs zip ys).map { case (x,y) => pow(y - x, 2) }.sum)
}

val testInstances = Array(Array(5.0, 4.8, 7.5, 10.0), Array(3.2, 2.1, 4.3, 2.8))
val trainPoints = Array(Array(3.9, 4.1, 6.2, 7.3), Array(4.5, 6.1, 8.3, 3.8), Array(5.2, 4.6, 7.4, 9.8), Array(5.1, 7.1, 4.4, 6.9))

distance(testInstances.head, trainPoints.head)
// 3.2680269276736382
```

As for predicting the class, you can make that more functional too, but it's unclear what the Double is that you are intending to return.  It seems like you would want to predict the class for each test instance?  Maybe choosing the class `c` corresponding to the nearest training point?

```
def findNearestClasses(testPoints: Array[Array[Double]], trainPoints: Array[Array[Double]]): Array[Int] = {
  testPoints.map { testInstance =>
    trainPoints.zipWithIndex.map { case (trainInstance, c) =>
      c -> distance(testInstance, trainInstance)
    }.minBy(_._2)._1
  }
}    

findNearestClasses(testInstances, trainPoints)
// Array(2, 0)
```

Or maybe you want the `k`-nearest neighbors:

```
def findKNearestClasses(testPoints: Array[Array[Double]], trainPoints: Array[Array[Double]], k: Int): Array[Int] = {
  testPoints.map { testInstance =>
    val distances = 
      trainPoints.zipWithIndex.map { case (trainInstance, c) =>
        c -> distance(testInstance, trainInstance)
      }
    val classes = distances.sortBy(_._2).take(k).map(_._1)
    val classCounts = classes.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
    classCounts.maxBy(_._2)._1
  }
}    

findKNearestClasses(testInstances, trainPoints)
// Array(2, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer. It has been very helpful. I have a few clarifications to make. Firstly, what does the line `distance(testInstances.head, trainPoints.head)` help in achieving? Does it subtract only the head elements and not the following ones?

Comment: Secondly, in the third block of code to find `kNearestNeighbours`, what does the output return? I want to return the index of the `testInstance` and the class associated with that index (for example, `Array((0, ClassA), (1, ClassB), (2, ClassA),...)`) and class for each testInstance is calculated using majority class vote of the k nearest neighbours (chosen from the `trainingPoints`). I will use the predictions to compare with the actual test dataset and compare its accuracy. How can I do this?

Comment: `distance(testInstances.head, trainPoints.head)` was just to demonstrate how it works.  It returns an Array of classes, with each array position corresponding to the test instance; if you want to attach the index as a tuple, that should be trivial with a `.map`.

Answer (score 0):

The generic formula for the euclidean distance is as follows:

```
math.sqrt(math.pow((x1 - x2), 2) + math.pow((y1 - y2), 2))
```

You can only compare the x coordinate with the x, and y with the y.